# $\sum_{n=1}^{4000000} \frac{1}{n^3}$ very quick.

Tags: riemann-zeta, polygamma

Some days ago I have tried to find the sum of the first milion terms of the infinite sum $\zeta(3) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^3}$ (Apéry's constant) on [Wolfram Programming Lab (Open Cloud)](https://lab.open.wolframcloud.com/app/), an online CAS. Therefore I wanted calculate: $\sum_{n=1}^{1000000}\frac{1}{n^3}$.

Since the calculation power available for free users is limited (and the `ParallelSum` function is not available online) I started evaluting `s[1]=Sum[1/(n^3),{n,1,100000}]`(the first one hundred thousand terms).
Then `s[2]=Sum[1/(n^3),{n,100001,200000}]` (the second one hundred thousand terms) and `s[3]=Sum[1/(n^3),{n,200001,300000}]` (the third one hundred thousand terms). Now the calculation `Sum[1/(n^3),{n,300001,400000}]` was aborted by the system because it exceeded the time limit.
I think that this calculations are very hard to do and all the previous calculations have required some time for the output on this very fast system.
Now I have input `s[4]=Sum[1/(n^3),{n,300001,350000}]` and the output was come out. And now for me was happen a strange thing. I make a typing error and I have input `s[5]=Sum[1/(n^3),{n,350001,4000000}]` (4 milions!), but the system very quickly output the following answer: `(1/2)(-PolyGamma[2,350001]+PolyGamma[2,4000001]`

Is it mathematically correct? I have make the sum `N[s[1]+s[2]+s[3]+s[4]+s[5]]` and compared with the know value of the Apéry's constant and it seems correct.

Comment: Therefore is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is mathematically correct.  See Eqn (11) in [MathWorld's Polygamma article](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolygammaFunction.html).
Accordingly, the result is
$$
\begin{align}
\tfrac{1}{2}(\psi_2 (4000001)-\psi_2 (3500001))&=\tfrac{1}{2}(-1)^3 2!\left( \zeta(3)-H^3_{4000000} - \zeta(3) + H^3_{3500000} \right)\\
&=-\left(\sum_{n=1}^{4000000}\frac{1}{n^3}-\sum_{n=1}^{3500000}\frac{1}{n^3}\right) \\
&=\sum_{n=3500001}^{4000000}\frac{1}{n^3}
\end{align}
$$
Mathematica decided that it was more useful to give you the Polygamma version of the sum rather than carry out the entire computation.